# how to apply layout to component conditionally in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am a bit new to react and stuck how to apply layout to component conditionally could someone help?

```
type Page<T = {}> = NextPage<T> & {
  layout?: React.ComponentType;
};

export default Page;

const MyPage:Page = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
  return (.....
};


MyPage.layout = isAuthenticated ? Layout1 : Layout2; //how to do such ??

export default MyPage;
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that per se as you can't access the `isAuthenticated` variable from outside the component.
You would need to have two components: one with the `Layout1` layout, and the second with the `Layout2` layout, and dynamically choose the one you want to load from the `MyPage` component.

Logged.ts

```
import Layout1 from '...';

const Logged: Page = () => <div>Logged in</div>;

Logged.layout = Layout1;

export default Logged;
```

NotLogged.ts

```
import Layout2 from '...';

const NotLogged: Page = () => <div>Please log in</div>;

NotLogged.layout = Layout2;

export default NotLogged;
```

MyPage.ts

```
import Logged from './Logged';
import NotLogged from './NotLogged';

const MyPage = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();

  return isAuthenticated ? <Logged /> : <NotLogged />;
};

export default MyPage;
```

Comment: thanks for reply to everyone but my question is more about how to organize export with setting layout (I updated a bit initial question) MyPage.layout = Layout1; (this works)
export default MyPage; but I dont understand how to get access isAuthenticated  right before export default

Comment: @qweqwe I updated my answer a bit but the conclusion is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operators are best used inside the return part of your component.

```
const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
const MyPage = () => <div>isAuthenticated ? Layout1 : Layout2</div>
export default MyPage;
```